Proper treatment of intermediate af::arrays in C++? When can I inline? When must I eval?
In most C++ programming, there are clear rules on when I can inline a variable.  What are those rules, in ArrayFire?  Let me illustrate with an example:
This is how I would generally structure this code:
af::array a = af::iota(af::dim4(3));
af::print("broken attempt",
          af::tile(a, 1, 3) - af::tile(a.T(), 3, 1));

But this does not work.  I prints:
[3 3 1 1]
   Offset: 0
   Strides: [1 3 9 9]
    0.0000     0.0000     0.0000
    0.0000     0.0000     0.0000
    0.0000     0.0000     0.0000 

If I increase the verbosity a lot, and throw in an eval, it works:
{
  af::array a = af::iota(af::dim4(3));
  af::array b = af::tile(a, 1, 3);
  af::array c = af::tile(a.T(), 3, 1);
  af::eval(c);
  af::print("working attempt", b - c);
}

prints
[3 3 1 1]
   Offset: 0
   Strides: [1 3 9 9]
    0.0000    -1.0000    -2.0000
    1.0000     0.0000    -1.0000
    2.0000     1.0000     0.0000 

If I comment out the af::eval(), it returns to the previous behavior of printing 0s.
What's going on, here?

More info:
$ uname -a
Linux my-laptop 6.6.63-1-lts #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Fri, 22 Nov 2024 15:39:56 +0000 x86_64 GNU/Linux

af::info()
ArrayFire v3.9.0 (OpenCL, 64-bit Linux, build default)
[0] AMD: gfx1103, 2048 MB -- OpenCL 2.0  -- Device driver 3625.0 (HSA1.1,LC) -- FP64 Support: True
-1- INTEL: AMD Ryzen 7 7840HS w/ Radeon 780M Graphics     , 62095 MB -- OpenCL 3.0 (Build 0) -- Device driver 2024.17.3.0.08_160000 -- FP64 Support: True

I tried running with AF_TRACE=all AF_JIT_KERNEL_TRACE=stdout.  The output didn't seem particularly useful, but is available on my post on the user group.
